# SQL Syntax error in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I have an issue with SQL syntax in import and export.

I receive messages saying I have syntax errors.

I've used `array_map` to strip slashes before processing in `mysql_query` (I know I should use mysqli, but this is a one-time use script).

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_jc_api_emailconnector` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`api_service_board` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`api_email_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`api_emailboard_quickreferral` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Can anyone explain why something like this will not run through mysql_query? It works just fine running via phpMyAdmin.

UPDATE:

Backup Query:

```
function backup_tables($tables_pull, $sessionName) {
  $db_backup_jc = new Database();
  $db_backup_jc->connectDB_1(); 
  $db_prefix_pull = $db_backup_jc->db_prefix_pull;  
  // Add Table Prefix of Database Tables

   //cycle through
   foreach($tables_pull as $table) {
    $add_prefix = $db_prefix_pull.$table;   
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$add_prefix);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);        
    $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$add_prefix.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$add_prefix));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$add_prefix.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
            {
                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
        }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n"; 
}
//save file
$handle = fopen('tmp/db-backup-'.$sessionName.'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
fclose($handle);
```

}

IMPORT QUERY:

```
function import_tables($filename_SQL) {
$db_get_prefix_1 = new Database();
$db_get_prefix_1->connectDB_1(); 
$db_prefix_1 = $db_get_prefix_1->db_prefix_pull;    

$db_get_prefix_2 = new Database();
$db_get_prefix_2->connectDB_2(); 
$db_prefix_2 = $db_get_prefix_2->db_prefix_push;

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = ''; 
$import_jc_SQL = file($filename_SQL);
$import_jc_SQL = array_map('stripslashes', $import_jc_SQL);
$import_jc_SQL = str_replace($db_prefix_1, $db_prefix_2, $import_jc_SQL);
foreach ($import_jc_SQL as $line) {     

    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;
    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;
    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
    {
        // Perform the query
        //mysql_query($templine, $conn_DB_2) or print('Error performing query' . mysql_error() . '<br />');
        // Reset temp variable to empty
        //$templine = '';
    }
}
mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query <br />' . mysql_error() . '<br />');
echo mysql_error();
```

}

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'0\',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 5

Comment: How do you process the mentioned statement?

Comment: you may want to change --- AUTO_INCREMENT=3 --- to --- AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ---. PHPMYADMIN Exported that file so Import it using it also. Use '' characters for mysql command line

Comment: I've added my backup/import functions to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are striping slashes hences in your error message you see `'\'0\',` extra slashes around `'0'`. You can:

- Remove the single quotes and only say `default 0` instead of `default '0'` or
- Do not strip slashes

I suggest the first one, since using `'0'` make it string and again another internal type converion is required to make it back int.

Comment: I've added my functions in the above code. The query I tested works using this switch and removing the quotes, but where in my function are they being added in? That is my question

Comment: `$import_jc_SQL = array_map('stripslashes', $import_jc_SQL);` where you are calling `stripslashes` function on `$import_jc_SQL`. That will escape the query.

Comment: I figured this out, and it's working now. Thanks for the input. This was added after the code was not working. This did fix the issue in my original code, but I added a few other parsing lines in the backup function, which was the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping quotes in your function. If removing the escaping is not an option, simply remove them first, as they aren't needed:

```
`api_emailboard_quickreferral` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

Comment: I've added my backup/import functions to my question. Take a look.